# How to show Time on DropDownList from Date on database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a date that I retrieve from database. I want to give ability to edit time on my gridview, as my date is date+time, I want to show the time on my database as my selected value on the dropdown list and a ability to choose other times from the list and save back again with date+time on the database.

What would be the best way to do this?

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Time" SortExpression="SelectionStartDate">

                  <EditItemTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="SelectionStarttime1" runat="server"  Text='<%# GetTime(Eval("SelectionStartDate", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}")) %>' Width="120px">                        
                         <asp:ListItem Value="10:00:00">Midday (12:00 AM)</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Value="17:00:00">End Day(05:00 PM)</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Value="23:59:59">Midnight End</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>  
                      </EditItemTemplate>                
                 <ItemTemplate>              
                    <asp:Label ID="lblStarttime1" runat="server" Text='<%# GetTime(Eval("SelectionStartDate", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}")) %>' ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

And I have the following on my VB

```
Protected Function GetTime(ByVal time As String) As String

        Return time.Substring(11)

    End Function
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`TimeSpan.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx) to convert your time part into a `TimeSpan` instance. Then you can add this to your Date instance to get the full DateTime.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
   Dim row = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
   Dim ddl =  DirectCast(row.FindControl("SelectionStarttime1"), DropDownList)
   Dim oldStartDate = Date.Parse(DirectCast(row.FindControl("HiddenStartDate"), HtmlInputHidden).Value)
   Dim newTime = TimeSpan.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue)
   Dim startDate = oldStartDate.Date.Add(newTime)
   SaveData(params) ' pseudo-code '
End Sub
```

Note that i've used a Hiddenfield(that you would have to add to your Template as well) to store the full datetime, you could also get it from your datasource directly(f.e. if stored in session or via query).